# Problems organizing "My Pictures" into folders

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am an artist and have literally hundreds of saved photos in "My Pictures". When I create folders and try to move the photos into the folders, everything jumps all over the place - the page jumps either all the way up or all the way down. I then have to scroll through hundreds of lines to find the folder I was working with.

Any ideas how I can stop this?

Comment: Do you want to keep your photos on your PC, or are you open to moving them on to the cloud, Picasa, flickr, etc?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_organizer.  Seem to recall some utility that provided a number of "drop boxes" where you could easily move pics from a "bulk" directory, into individualized subdirs?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

1. Opening two windows
2. Creating the target folders somewhere else (not where all the pictures are)
3. Moving the folders back once all the pictures are sorted.

This way, creating folders etc won't cause Explorer to re-sort your list of images every time the directory contents changes.

Changing the sort order in Explorer might also help.